# Python: Trying to Deserialize Multiple JSON objects in a file with each object spanning multiple but consistently spaced number of lines

Tags: python, json

Ok, after nearly a week of research I'm going to give SO a shot. I have a text file that looks as follows (showing 3 separate json objects as an example but file has 50K of these):

```
{
"zipcode":"00544",
"current":{"canwc":null,"cig":7000,"class":"observation"},
"triggers":[178,30,176,103,179,112,21,20,48,7,50,40,57]
}
{
"zipcode":"00601",
"current":{"canwc":null,"cig":null,"class":"observation"},
"triggers":[12,23,34,28,100]
}
{
"zipcode":"00602",
"current":{"canwc":null,"cig":null,"class":"observation"},
"triggers":[13,85,43,101,38,31]
}
```

I know how to work with JSON objects using the Python json library but I'm having a challenge with how to create 50 thousand different json objects from reading the file. (Perhaps I'm not even thinking about this correctly but ultimately I need to deserialize and load into a database) I've tried itertools thinking that I need a generator so I was able to use:

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in itertools.islice(f, 0, 7): #since every 7 lines is a json object
        jfile = json.load(line)
```

But the above obviously won't work since it is not reading the 7 lines as a single json object and I'm also not sure how to then iterate on entire file and load individual json objects.

The following would give me a list I can slice:

```
list(open(file))[:7]
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

---

Extemely close to what I need and I think literally one step away but still struggling a little with iteration. This will finally get me an iterative printout of all of the dataframes but how do I make it so that I can capture one giant dataframe with all of the pieces essentially concatenated? I could then export that final dataframe to csv etc. (Also is there a better way to upload this result into a database rather than creating a giant dataframe first?)

```
def lines_per_n(f, n):
    for line in f:
        yield ''.join(chain([line], itertools.islice(f, n - 1)))

def flatten(jfile):
    for k, v in jfile.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            jfile[k] = ','.join(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for kk, vv in v.items():
                jfile['%s' % (kk)] = vv
            del jfile[k]
            return jfile

with open('deadzips.json') as f:
    for chunk in lines_per_n(f, 7):
        try:
            jfile = json.loads(chunk)
            pd.DataFrame(flatten(jfile).items())
        except ValueError, e:
            pass
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being stupid; but isn't every 5 lines a json object? Based on your sample anyway..

Comment: @daveL I see what you are saying and I probably worded it poorly but I meant being able to load each of those individual chunks which make up one json object and then being able to process each one individually.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Load 6 extra lines instead, and pass the *string* to `json.loads()`:

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        # slice the next 6 lines from the iterable, as a list.
        lines = [line] + list(itertools.islice(f, 6))
        jfile = json.loads(''.join(lines))

        # do something with jfile
```

`json.load()` will slurp up more than just the next object in the file, and `islice(f, 0, 7)` would read only the first 7 lines, rather than read the file in 7-line blocks.

You can wrap reading a file in blocks of size N in a generator:

```
from itertools import islice, chain

def lines_per_n(f, n):
    for line in f:
        yield ''.join(chain([line], itertools.islice(f, n - 1)))
```

then use that to chunk up your input file:

```
with open(file) as f:
    for chunk in lines_per_n(f, 7):
        jfile = json.loads(chunk)

        # do something with jfile
```

Alternatively, if your blocks turn out to be of variable length, read until you have something that parses:

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        while True:
            try:
                jfile = json.loads(line)
                break
            except ValueError:
                # Not yet a complete JSON value
                line += next(f)

        # do something with jfile
```

Comment: As for your second solution, `JSONDecoder.raw_decode` basically does this for you.

Comment: @stephan However, beware that `JSONDecoder.raw_decode` currently can't handle [leading whitespace](http://bugs.python.org/issue15393).

Comment: @stephan: up to a point, yes. I've used both approaches, depending on how well structured the file is. If the objects are delimited by newlines and most snippets are short one-liners, the exception handler approach is nice and fast.

Comment: @stephan: Note that `JSONDecoder.raw_decode` only works with an input string, not a file object, so you'd have to handle buffering of lines read yourself. You could read x lines, try to parse, and add lines as needed as the raw decoder finds objects. But when delimited by newlines, my second approach is just much more convenient.

Comment: This is truly fantastic and much appreciated. I really like being able to call the lines_per_n function and I can then process that chunk. Sorry about the dumb question as I am still learning how to apply generators but how migth I be able to apply my processing to all of the objects in the file as opposed to just the first one? In other words run the process on first chunk then automatically run the process on subsequent chunks until end of file?

Comment: @prometheus2305: That is exactly what the generator *does*; it produces chunks of n lines from your file as an iterable. Just use a loop, as illustrated in my answer.

Comment: Updated my code. It's a lot of what I want to accomplish and the suggestions were very helpful but it looks like I'm just missing how to make sure it processes all chunks.

Comment: @prometheus2305: your loop looks correct to me, provided you do something with the `df` object in the loop too. Otherwise the next iteration of the loop replaces the previous dataframe without making use of it.

Comment: I'm hoping that I am incredibly close. Updated question. Any suggestions would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: @prometheus2305: In `flatten()`, is the `return jfile.items()` really indented that far? You probably do not want to return the first iteration of that loop.

Comment: @prometheus2305: You probably want to test your components individually; try out `flatten()` on *one* chunk first, for example, to see if it returns what you expect.

Comment: Updated question to my nearly final version. Would really appreciate some advice. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

As stated elsewhere, a general solution is to read the file in pieces, append each piece to the last, and try to parse that new chunk.  If it doesn't parse, continue until you get something that does.  Once you have something that parses, return it, and restart the process.  Rinse-lather-repeat until you run out of data.

Here is a succinct generator that will do this:

```
def load_json_multiple(segments):
    chunk = ""
    for segment in segments:
        chunk += segment
        try:
            yield json.loads(chunk)
            chunk = ""
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Use it like this:

```
with open('foo.json') as f:
   for parsed_json in load_json_multiple(f):
      print parsed_json
```

I hope this helps.