# How to extract the particular information from a text file using python?

Tags: python

I am learning file concepts in python. Here i want to extract some text from text file (which is in **bold format**). But i don't know how to do it.

Here my sample text file:

{"glossary":{ "title": "example glossary","GlossDiv": {**"title": "S"**,"GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"ID": "SGML","SortAs": "SGML","GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
"Acronym": "SGML","Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef": {**"para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."**,"GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]},
"GlossSee": "markup"}}}}}

{"glossary":{ "title": "example glossary","GlossDiv": {**"title": "a"**,"GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"ID": "SGML","SortAs": "SGML","GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
"Acronym": "SGML","Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef": {**"para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."**,"GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]},
"GlossSee": "markup"}}}}}

{"glossary":{ "title": "example glossary","GlossDiv": {**"title": "b"**,"GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"ID": "SGML","SortAs": "SGML","GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
"Acronym": "SGML","Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef": {**"para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."**,"GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]},
"GlossSee": "markup"}}}}}

{"glossary":{ "title": "example glossary","GlossDiv": {**"title": "c"**,"GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"ID": "SGML","SortAs": "SGML","GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
"Acronym": "SGML","Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef": {**"para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."**,"GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]},
"GlossSee": "markup"}}}}}

{"glossary":{ "title": "example glossary","GlossDiv": {**"title": "f"**,"GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"ID": "SGML","SortAs": "SGML","GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
"Acronym": "SGML","Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef": {**"para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."**,"GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]},
"GlossSee": "markup"}}}}

And i need output like this:

```
"title": "S" ; "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."
"title": "a" ; "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook."
....
```

can anyone help me to do this in python?

Comment: Hints: JSON, JSON Parsing using python

Comment: I learned some json and python basic programs.I don't get anything till now. And i don't know how to do this program. Help me

Comment: What are the circumstances here? How are you in the position of having to write a program in a language you don't know? Also, it is difficult to tell the format of your data file if you line wrap it and put sections in bold. We get it: you want the `title` and the `para` values from the data, and it is easier to say that than **bolding** sections of your data. Please copy and paste the *exact* data and indent it by four spaces so that it doesn't line wrap; then we will be able to see its structure properly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: No, the default Python `repr` uses single quotes for strings without quotes in them. This is almost certainly JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no attempt was given to show any code I'll only give some general advice. Each of the lines in the file is actually a Python data structure known as a `dictionary`. You can read each line and use the Python's `json` library to parse it and store it as a Dictionary(`dict`). More on Python Dictionaries can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> **5.5. Dictionaries**
> Another useful data type built into Python is the dictionary (see Mapping Types — dict). Dictionaries are sometimes found in other languages as “associative memories” or “associative arrays”. Unlike sequences, which are indexed by a range of numbers, dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any immutable type; strings and numbers can always be keys. Tuples can be used as keys if they contain only strings, numbers, or tuples; if a tuple contains any mutable object either directly or indirectly, it cannot be used as a key. You can’t use lists as keys, since lists can be modified in place using index assignments, slice assignments, or methods like append() and extend().
>
> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary). A pair of braces creates an empty dictionary: {}. Placing a comma-separated list of key:value pairs within the braces adds initial key:value pairs to the dictionary; this is also the way dictionaries are written on output.
>
> The main operations on a dictionary are storing a value with some key and extracting the value given the key. It is also possible to delete a key:value pair with del. If you store using a key that is already in use, the old value associated with that key is forgotten. It is an error to extract a value using a non-existent key.

Some ideas for reading multiple JSON objects from a file can be found in the accepted answer of this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400818/python-trying-to-deserialize-multiple-json-objects-in-a-file-with-each-object-s). In particular the last sample code snippet.

Once read into a dictionary you can perform dictionary lookups on the data. If I read the dictionary into a variable named `dictvar` then I could print the `glossary` `title` by doing something like this:

```
print (dictvar['glossary']['title'])
```

and if I was reading the first example in your file above that would print:

```
example glossary
```

You can actually produce a program that does what you want with a minimal amount of code

Comment: You are probably right but I think the OP has a steep learning curve even with the info provided.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: You didn't addreess one of the toughest parts of the task: reading compllete datablocks from the file one at a time. Luckily it seems that they are separated by blank lines.

Comment: Using `eval` to parse JSON data is a bad idea. It's conceptually wrong to use the wrong tool just because it happens to work. It's also unsafe. And it provides less detection of corrupted input, and is slower to boot.

Comment: (If you're wondering how I know this is JSON: While it's legal as a Python literal, it's not something that `repr` will ever generate, because `repr` prefers single quotes to double. Try `repr({"a": "b"})`.)

Comment: The data is coming from "a text file". You're just going to assume that's safe? And meanwhile, even if it is, why use something that's conceptually wrong, less likely to detect corruption, and as much as an order of magnitude slower? (Also, what exactly would you use `setattr` for here?)

Comment: Unless of course someone created a class and overrode repr ;-)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Well, in that case they're not dicts, they're instances of some class that we know nothing about… :)

Comment: No they could be a class derived from `dict` (as a base class) that simply overrode `__repr__`. A derived class would still be a dict with new functionality ;-)

Comment: I got the answer. Using json and python dictionary. And, the code is here: #!/usr/bin/python
import json
data = []
file=open("sss.txt",'r')
for line in file:
 data=json.loads(line)
 print data.get('title')
        print data.get('para')