# Appending many JSON objects to a list from a file

Tags: python

I have a file with multiple JSON objects. How would I create a list of these JSON objects? These JSON objects are placed one after another without any particular formatting besides JSON. I looked around and someone mentioned multiple `json.load()` but I'm not sure how to implement this. I am open to other suggestions as well

The structure of the JSON is structured like so

```
{
 "data" : "1",
 "app" : "test1",
 "timestamp" : 141533423
}
{
 "data" : "1",
 "app" : "test1",
}
{
 "data" : "1",
 "app" : "test1",
 "timestamp" : 141533423,
 "device" : [{"iphone" : "6", "value" : 8}],
 "color" : "blue"
}
{
 "data" : "3",
 "timestamp" : 143431533423
}
```

Comment: How is the JSON file structured? `{}{}{}...`? An example of the file would help out quite a bit.

Comment: @OozeMeister sorry yes like so `{}{}{}...`

Comment: This is a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400818/python-trying-to-deserialize-multiple-json-objects-in-a-file-with-each-object-s