# Extracting data in Tweepy in useable form (JSON)

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I am using Tweepy to gather data on followers. I am able to print the returned data, but no matter what I try, I can't save the data to a file in a reuseable form.

Below is the way that I got it to successfully export to a txt file, but when I call that file into a variable, it sets up a character array and doesn't see it as a useable array.

Here is the Tweepy call:

```
import sys
import tweepy
import json

# Key info removed

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

ids = []
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="handle").pages():
    ids.extend(page)
print ids

with open("followers.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(ids))
```

What I get from that is a file that starts:

```
[User(follow_request_sent=False...
```

If I call the data in with

```
data = f.read()
print data[0]  # returns '['
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `page` is a `list` of tweepy `User` objects.  So you're losing your tweepy data structure when you:  `ids.extend(page)`.

Try this bit of code below:

```
with open("followers.txt", 'a') as f:     #open file first
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name='handle').pages():
        for user_obj in page:   #iterate through each User object
            json.dump(user_obj._json, f)  #dump each to file, f
            f.write("\n")  #you'll need this for Martjin's answer below to work.
```

Thanks to Martjin Pieter's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400818/python-trying-to-deserialize-multiple-json-objects-in-a-file-with-each-object-s).  You can load and discretely access your data.  The way I modified his code snippet is so that `jfile` is appened to a list called `user_jsons` (which would be equivalent to your `data` variable).

```
user_jsons = []
with open("followers.txt", 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        while True:
            try:
                jfile = json.loads(line)
                break
            except ValueError:
                # Not yet a complete JSON value
                line += next(f)
        user_jsons.append(jfile)
```

Now you have a list of json objects...  [7] is truncated

```
In [7]: user_jsons[0]
Out[7]: {u'blocked_by': False,
          u'blocking': False,
          u'contributors_enabled': False,
          u'created_at': u'Thu Jan 30 18:33:13 +0000 2014',
          ...

In [8]: user_jsons[0]['screen_name']
Out[8]: u'some_users_handle'
```

You may find the ipython notebooks [here](https://github.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition) a very useful resource, chapter 9 in particular.

Comment: Thanks for that. I ran it, but I still don't get valid json out in the first segment. I pasted the followers.txt file into json viewer and it didn't read it, and I tried the second part, and got this error `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`. I can't make sense of the file as it has so many layers, but it strangely starts with a list, but does not name a follower until later in the file `[User(follow_request_sent=False, has_extended_profile=False, profile_use_background_image=False, _json={u'follow_request_sent': False, u'has_extended_profile': False, `

Comment: When you run my first block of code, it should generate a followers.txt file.  That will have *several* jsons embedded in it, it won't be recognized as a single json.  
Did you change any part of the code?  I just copy/pasted it and it worked.
Another option is you could easily save each User as a `.json` file, let me  know if you want me to edit so you can try this.  But if there are 1000s of followers, you'll have 1000s of files with this option.

Comment: Copy the contents of one json from `followers.txt` into a txt file, then upload that to jsonviewer as a test. One json will start with `{` and end with  `}` then a newline character.

Comment: Ok. I got it now. That makes sense. I was able to print out 1 by itself and it passed as json.

Answer (score 1):

you can save the file first by using

```
f.close()
```

it will save your data into the file and then you can use this

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('followers.txt') as new_file:    
    new_file = json.load(new_file)

pprint(data)
```

and you can refer original python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to see more about reading methods in a file in python.

hope it may help !

Comment: I tried that, though I set data = json.load(new_file) as I think this is what you meant. I get an error: "raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: could you tell me the scema of followers.txt file in a snippet ?

Comment: It's a huge file that won't load into jsonviewer, so it's difficult to see the entire structure. I don't know if this helps, but this is the first part: `[User(follow_request_sent=False, has_extended_profile=False, profile_use_background_image=False, _json={u'follow_request_sent': False, u'has_extended_profile': `  This beginning doesn't make sense to me.