# Parsing JSON lines with JQ for flapping key values in sequence

Tags: json, jq

I have a file containing json lines that need to be verified for its validity based on the sequence of each json's flapping "alert.status" value.

A sample of valid json lines:

```
{"id":123,"code":"foo","severity":"Critical","severityCode":1, "property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"On"}}
{"id":456,"code":"bar","severity":"High","severityCode":2,"property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"On"}}
{"id":123,"code":"foo","severity":"Critical","severityCode":1,"property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"Off"}}
{"id":456,"code":"bar","severity":"High","severityCode":2,"property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"Off"}}
{"id":123,"code":"foo","severity":"Critical","severityCode":1,"property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"On"}}
{"id":456,"code":"bar","severity":"High","severityCode":2,"property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"On"}}
```

The above file is valid since the duplicate jsons (line 1,5 and line 2,6) have status flapping from "on", "off", "on" and so on.

A sample of invalid json lines:

```
{"id":123,"code":"foo","severity":"Critical","severityCode":1, "property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"On"}}
{"id":456,"code":"bar","severity":"High","severityCode":2,"property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"On"}}
{"id":123,"code":"foo","severity":"Critical","severityCode":1,"property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"On"}}
{"id":456,"code":"bar","severity":"High","severityCode":2,"property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"Off"}}
{"id":123,"code":"foo","severity":"Critical","severityCode":1,"property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"Off"}}
{"id":456,"code":"bar","severity":"High","severityCode":2,"property":{ "priority":"top", "owner":"dev"}, "alert":{"mgmt":"yes", "status":"Off"}}
```

The above is invalid since jsons in line 1 and 3 are duplicate having its "status" value stays the same without flapping from on or off.

I tried to use jq to read the json lines into a json array

```
jq --slurp 'map(select(. >= 2))' jsonfile > jsonarray
```

But since the sequence in each line is important, I don't think I can use group_by to look for duplicates (the group_by's result is sorted).

I'm thinking about inserting a new key with incremental number in each json so after using group_by, we can sort the result based on this new key to get back the sequence.

Is there a way in jq to use group by all except two keys? (in this case "status" and the new key with incremental number).

Is there any better approach how to solve this problem?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Which values do you use to decide if two records are "the same"? `.id` and `.code`?

Comment: All of them, but the status can only "on" or "off" in sequence (flapping), it can't stay the same next to each other

Comment: I've posted an example in Python. Let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 4):

> I don't think I can use group_by to look for duplicates (the group_by's result is sorted).

That's right, but it's very easy to define a non-sorting "group_by", which, as we'll see, can also easily be used to sort by all keys except for specifically designated ones.

#### GROUPS_BY

First, here is a simple filter which retains the original order of items within each group:

```
# The filter, f, must produce a string for each item in `stream`
def GROUPS_BY(stream; f):
  reduce stream as $x ({}; .[$x|f] += [$x] ) | .[] ;
```

The "S" in the name emphasizes that the function is stream-oriented, first in that the first argument is a stream, and second in that the function produces a stream of the groups; the name is upper-cased to emphasize the differences with the existing built-in function.

#### Example

To illustrate how this can be used to group by all but a specific key, consider this example (taken from another SO question):

```
def data:
  [{"foo":1,"bar":"a","baz":"whatever"},
   {"foo":1,"bar":"a","baz":"hello"},
   {"foo":1,"bar":"b","baz":"world"}] ;

GROUPS_BY(data[]; del(.baz) | tostring)
```

#### Output

```
[{"foo":1,"bar":"a","baz":"whatever"},{"foo":1,"bar":"a","baz":"hello"}]
[{"foo":1,"bar":"b","baz":"world"}]
```

#### Refinement

It may be objected that requiring that f always be string-valued introduces several potential difficulties, so here is an efficient but more versatile definition:

```
# Emit a stream of the groups defined by f, without using sort.
# f need not be string-valued.
def GROUPS_BY(stream; f): 
   reduce stream as $x ({};
     ($x|f) as $s
     | ($s|type) as $t
     | (if $t == "string" then $s else ($s|tojson) end) as $y
     | .[$t][$y] += [$x] )
   | .[][]
   ;
```

Now we can simply write:

```
GROUPS_BY(data[]; del(.baz))
```

#### Usage with the JSON-Lines file

The simplest way to use `GROUPS_BY` with a JSON-Lines file is with `inputs`, e.g. assuming the more versatile def is used, you'd write:

```
GROUPS_BY(inputs; del(.alert))
```

Don't forget to invoke jq with the -n option when using `inputs`.

#### A filter to determine validity

According to my understanding of the problem, the following filter can be used to determine validity of a group:

```
def changing(f):
  def c:
    if length <= 1 then true
    elif (.[0] | f) == (.[1] | f) then false
    else .[1:] | c
    end;
  c ;
```

(The inner function, c, is used here for efficient recursion. Of course, if computing `f` redundantly is a concern, then a variant definition should be used.)

#### Solution

Putting it altogether using the more versatile definition of GROUPS_BY,
and assuming we wish to identify the invalid groups, the solution seems to be a two-liner:

```
GROUPS_BY(inputs; del(.alert))
| select( changing(.alert.status) | not )
```

Comment: Where can I place the custom module used by jq? Sorry I'm a newbie to this.

Comment: There is no custom module.  You can put all the pieces of the jq program in a single file, say program.jq, and invoke it like this: jq -n -f program.jq input.json

Comment: @peak I'm, as always, impressed by your deep understanding of the `jq` language (and your will to explain it) ^1. But honestly, would you recommend to use such complex filters in real life, I mean in a production environment? Imo it suffers from readability and maintainability (by everybody in the team)

Comment: PS: I'm not saying that the `load_json_multiple()` function I've used is really production-ready ;). I'm not happy with that, but unfortunately there seems no other way in Python.

Comment: @hek2mgl - Thanks for the compliment(s) - but what is "^1"?  I think that the more versatile/complex GROUPS_BY (or something very much like it) belongs in jq itself, which would make the overall solution rather simple, but even if the user has to include it in the program, I don't see any reason why that would make any significant difference in any decision to use jq in a production environment.  My main concern with respect to use of jq in a production environment would be "vendor support". In other words, it really depends on the specific requirements of the "production environment".

Comment: `^1` meant *upvote* ;) Probably the term *production* was a bit misleading. I meant in a corporate, work place environment. While the company I'm working in for example makes a heavy use of jq for little to medium complex filters in shell scripts, Python (or something comparable) turns out to be the better choice for more complex tasks (like in this thread). Chances are that a complex jq program would be hard to maintain for those which are not jq gurus (like peak ;) ). And probably even for those who are when the use case changes.

Comment: But yeah, including `GROUPS_BY` into the jq distribution would reduce the complexity here.

Comment: Do you think GROUPS_BY should emit the stream of groups (i.e. [grouped_item1, grouped_item2, ...] ...) or the stream: [group_id1, [grouped_item1, grouped_item2, ...]] ... ?

Comment: Intuitionally I would choose the latter because it preserves the group_id. But I'm not sure if I fully understand the consequences and how well that would integrate with existing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in a more convenient programming language, like Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import sys
```

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/38373810/171318

```
def load_json_multiple(segments):
    chunk = ""
    for segment in segments:
        chunk += segment
        try:
            yield json.loads(chunk)
            chunk = ""
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

... and the `main()` method:

```
def main():

    lookup = {}
    # You might wanna use argparse for this in real life
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    with open(filename) as f:
        for parsed_json in load_json_multiple(f):
            key = '{}/{}/{}'.format(parsed_json['id'],
                                    parsed_json['code'],
                                    parsed_json['severityCode'])

            status = True if parsed_json['alert']['status'] == 'On' else False
            if key in lookup and lookup[key] != (not status):
                print('invalid')
                return 1

            lookup[key] = status

    print('valid')
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Store it in a file, let's say *validate.py*, `chmod +x` it and call it like this:

```
./validate.py valid.json
./validate.py invalid.json
...
```