# JQ: Merge Entries if some key values are identical

Tags: json, object, merge, jq

I would like to merge entries of a json file with jq.

If values of some defined keys are matching, I'd like to merge the entries. The data which does not match should be stored in an array.
I provided some example JSON for this case.

If the street and the house number are identical, I'd like to merge this entry and put the values of "member" into an array.

**Matching keys**: housenumber + street have to be identical.

Example Input

```
[{
 "street"  : "Foobar ave",
 "housenumber": 4,
 "member":"Carl"
 },
 {
 "street"  : "Foobar ave",
 "housenumber": 4,
 "member":"Bernd"
 },
 {
 "street"  : "Foobar ave",
 "housenumber": 2,
 "member":"Ann"
 }]
```

Target result:

```
[{
 "street"  : "Foobar ave",
 "housenumber": 4,
 "members":["Carl","Bernd"]
 },
 {
 "street"  : "Foobar ave",
 "housenumber": 2,
 "members":["Ann"]
 }]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following uses the versatile and efficient version of `GROUPS_BY` defined at [Parsing JSON lines with JQ for flapping key values in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105506)

(`GROUPS_BY` is an efficient version of the built-in `group_by`, which you could also use, as shown below.)

`GROUPS_BY` is stream-oriented.  Thus the "natural" use of `GROUPS_BY` to solve the problem at hand is:

```
  GROUPS_BY(.[]; [.street, .housenumber])
  | (.[0]|del(.member)) + { members: (map(.member)) }
```

This produces a stream of the "groups", while preserving the ordering of the "members":

```
{"street":"Foobar ave","housenumber":4,"members":["Carl","Bernd"]}
{"street":"Foobar ave","housenumber":2,"members":["Ann"]}
```

If you require that the result be an array, then simply wrap the two-line program above in square brackets: [ .... ]

#### Solution using built-in `group_by`

Currently, `group_by` uses a sorting algorithm, which means that the ordering of the "members" might not be preserved:

```
group_by( [.street, .housenumber])
| map((.[0]|del(.member)) + { members: (map(.member)) })
```

#### Generic Solution using melds_by/2

Given a stream of objects and a grouping criterion, f, `melds_by` emits 
a stream of pairs of the form:

```
 [groupid, melded_object]
```

where `melded_object` is an object constructed from the objects in the "groupid" group, with all the keys present in this group, and where the value at each key is the array of corresponding values:

```
def melds_by(stream; f):
  GROUPS_BY(stream; f)
  | . as $in
  | [ (.[0]|f),
      reduce (add|keys[]) as $k ({}; .[$k] = [$in[] | .[$k]]) ]
  ;
```

To obtain the solution to the original problem as a single array, we can simply write:

```
[ melds_by(.[]; {street, housenumber})
  | .[1] + .[0]
  | with_entries(.key |= if . == "member" then "members" else . end) ]
```

The last line above simply renames the "member" key.

Comment: Thanks for your help :).