# Python: parse multiple JSON objects from one txt file

Tags: python, json

I'm rephrasing the question asked here.  [Python: Trying to Deserialize Multiple JSON objects in a file with each object spanning multiple but consistently spaced number of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400818/python-trying-to-deserialize-multiple-json-objects-in-a-file-with-each-object-s)

and other posts. But I'm new to JSON and I don't quite know how many of the functions are supposed to work, especially to suit my purpose. I'm working on python 3 with numpy and pandas as well, and was curious if there was any functions that could simplify this.

I'm trying to save multiple requests from the google maps API. That API returns a JSON object, one dictionary, of about 52 lines. I have a large dataset and I was hoping to get around 5000 of these JSON objects. I created a function that writes the all of the json objects into one txt file. I have one newline character in between each json object. Here's the code for that... all of this is in a loop that constantly makes requests to the google maps api

```
    r = requests.get(url, params=payload) # request
    json_var = r.json()
    json_var['tweet_id'] = rows['tweet_id']
    json_var['manual_location'] = manual_loc
    if small==True:
        print("writing")
        with open("txt_files/small_geo_json.txt", 'a') as myfile:
            myfile.write(json.dumps(json_var, indent=4))
            myfile.write("\n")
```

I borrowed code from the solution, hoping i interpreted it correctly. I think "n" is supposed to be how many lines your json object takes up, however...

```
def lines_per_n(f, n):
  for line in f:
    yield ''.join(chain([line], itertools.islice(f, n - 1)))

def extract_cords_from_json(small=False):
  if small == True:
    data =[]
    with open("txt_files/small_geo_json.txt") as infile:
        for chunk in lines_per_n(infile, 52):
            print(chunk)
            jfile = json.loads(chunk)
```

Here's an example json object from the requests.get() call:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "address_components": [
            {
                "long_name": "United States",
                "short_name": "US",
                "types": [
                    "country",
                    "political"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "formatted_address": "United States",
        "geometry": {
            "bounds": {
                "northeast": {
                    "lat": 71.5388001,
                    "lng": -66.885417
                },
                "southwest": {
                    "lat": 18.7763,
                    "lng": 170.5957
                }
            },
            "location": {
                "lat": 37.09024,
                "lng": -95.712891
            },
            "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport": {
                "northeast": {
                    "lat": 49.38,
                    "lng": -66.94
                },
                "southwest": {
                    "lat": 25.82,
                    "lng": -124.39
                }
            }
        },
        "place_id": "ChIJCzYy5IS16lQRQrfeQ5K5Oxw",
        "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
        ]
    }
],
"status": "OK",
"tweet_id": 974072,
"manual_location": "United States"
}
```

It's pretty long. The results of the code from running the functions I posted, however...
This doesn't quite work as expected. The output that it produces (I found this out by printing the `chunk` variable) actually  has 105 lines (which I mean, 52 * 2 = 104. It's close to around that). The 105 output actually doesn't have two full entries. It seems to have the first 52 lines for one json object, then there's a blank line, then there's the first 29 lines of another json object.

The error I get is:
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:
 line 53 column 1 (char 1598)`

I also tried using https://jsonlint.com/ and copied/pasted my text file. It gives the following error, but I don't know what it means.

```
 Error: Parse error on line 48:
 ...: "United States"} {    "results": [{       "
 ----------------------^
 Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

Comment: Do you really need to write a bunch of separate JSON objects into one file? Why not just write a single JSON object, which is a list containing all your sub-objects?

Comment: yeah I don't need to save them all to different JSON objects. I was google searching "JSON Array in python" and wasn't finding anything, however, so I gave up on the idea that you could do that.

So I could create a list object, append each of the json objects to it, then save that?

Comment: You most certainly can do that. The outermost container in JSON is usually an object, which becomes a dict when loaded into Python, but it's perfectly legal to make that outermost container a list.

Comment: You can make save those JSON as Dict on a python file, Things will be lot easier, I guess. 

And if you have any unique id, or key make it's dict key:

save in this format 
`dict = {
"unique_key": {"Extracted Dict/JSON goes here"},
#append another row here in the same fashion
}`

Comment: @Rajan Sure, if you _have_ a unique key for each of those sub-objects it makes sense to save them all into a dict. But if you don't have or need such a key, then a list is perfectly ok.